# Pre-trained checkpoints (.chkpt) Vs GraphDef (.pb)

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, pre-trained-model

I am trying to extract features of a new data-set by using a pre-trained network like that one classify_image_graph_def.pb released by Google in the tensorflow (inception-2015-12-05.tgz). I was successful on that as there is tutorial at [transfer_learning](https://github.com/oduerr/dl_tutorial/tree/master/tensorflow/inception_cifar10), which uses the classify_image_graph_def.pb (inception_v3.pb) to extract fractures of the new data-set.

However, in the new release of pre-trained models tensorflow provides check point files (ex. resnet_v1_152.ckpt) instead of Graph_def (ex. resnet_v1_152.pb). I was wondering how I could use these checkpoint files to extract features as in [transfer_learning](https://github.com/oduerr/dl_tutorial/tree/master/tensorflow/inception_cifar10). Could anyone give me some directions?

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the official model save/restore doc [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/saved_model).